# How to make clone or extended mode

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I am having multiple monitors(virtual+real) and by default I wanted to put it in clone/dual mode from my program. Can some one suggest how do I achieve this? I am very new to this world:) sorry for this basic question.... even any doc or any link will be highly appreciable.

/sarbojit

Answer (score 5):

```
//Extend
SetDisplayConfig(0, NULL,0, NULL,(SDC_APPLY | SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND));
//Clone
SetDisplayConfig(0, NULL,0, NULL,(SDC_APPLY | SDC_TOPOLOGY_CLONE));
```

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff569533%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

To set clone displays in Win7, this will work if there are 2 paths and 4 modes

```
UINT32 cPath=0;  //path count
UINT32 cMode=0;  //mode count
HRESULT hr;
hr = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATH, &cPath, &cMode);
std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> pathArray(cPath);
std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> modeArray(cMode);
hr =QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_ALL_PATHS, &cPath, &pathArray[0], &cMode, &modeArray[0], NULL);
if(hr != ERROR_SUCCESS) { problem in paradise }
if(cPath!=2 || cMode != 4) { anything else is too complex or a single display or already cloned }
// to change resolution also
// int ix=pathArray[0].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx;  assuming path[0] is primary, it should be
// modeArray[ix].sourceMode.width = 320;       // :(
// modeArray[ix].sourceMode.hieght = 240;      // :(
pathArray[1].flags |= DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_ACTIVE;
pathArray[1].sourceInfo.modeIdx = pathArray[0].sourceInfo.modeIdx;   //same source
pathArray[1].sourceInfo.id = pathArray[0].sourceInfo.id;       //same source
hr = SetDisplayConfig(cPath, &pathArray[0], cMode, &modeArray[0], SDC_APPLY | SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG | SDC_ALLOW_CHANGE | SDC_SAVE_TO_DATABASE));
if(hr != ERROR_SUCCESS) { so close!!! }
```

Comment: thank man, this magical line {pathArray[1].flags |= DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_ACTIVE;} saved my year 

Answer (score 2):

- [Changing display settings
  programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx)
- [Example of attaching a monitor and
  its issues in earlier version of
  Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308216/en-gb)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be on Windows XP and have an NVIDIA card you can use the following command line command

```
rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg setview 1 clone
```

or

```
rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg setview 1 dualview
```

and use CreateProcess to create a child process which runs that command. I have been unable to get NvAPI to set up clone or extended mode on Windows XP, but it seems to run fine on Windows 7.