# MultiMonitorSetup: Duplicate Desktop between secondary monitors programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, multiple-monitors, mirror

I want to programmatically switch between following two modes:

[image: example image]

I already tried to use the [`SetDisplayConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533(v=vs.85).aspx) Function, but failed. With following command it is possible to clone the **main monitor** to all attached displays:

```
SetDisplayConfig(0, null, 0, null, 
    SetDisplayConfigFlags.SDC_TOPOLOGY_CLONE | SetDisplayConfigFlags.SDC_APPLY);
```

Unfortunately I need to duplicate **secondary** monitors!

I found another approach in question [How to make clone or extended mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625983/how-to-make-clone-or-extended-mode/11005006#11005006). But I can't getting it working to set the source for different display to the same reference.

Answer (score 4):

**Working Solution for Windows 7:**

To clone/duplicate the desktop between two (or more) connected devices, all you have to do is to:

1. QueryDisplayConfig()
2. Share the 'sourceInfo.id' and 'sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx' for all 'PathInfoArray'-Items which you want to duplicate the desktop. e.g. duplicate display 'index 1' to Display with Index '2 and 3':

   - PathInfoArray[2].sourceInfo.id = PathInfoArray[1].sourceInfo.id
   - PathInfoArray[2].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx = PathInfoArray[1].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx
   - PathInfoArray[3].sourceInfo.id = PathInfoArray[1].sourceInfo.id
   - PathInfoArray[3].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx = PathInfoArray[1].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx
3. SetDisplayConfig()

---

To Extend the Display between two or more Displays (if displays are cloned), it is a little more trickier:

1. QueryDisplayConfig()
2. Add a 'SourceModeInfo' Item with infoType 'Source' foreach additional Clone Display to the 'SourceModeInfoArray': If two Displays configured you need one additionaly 'SourceModeInfo' Item (if three were cloned => 2 Items, and so on)
3. Extend PathInfoArray for one of the cloned displays to point to the Additional 'SourceModeInfo' - Item:

   - PathInfoArray[2].sourceInfo.id = AddItem.sourceInfo.id;
   - PathInfoArray[2].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx = AddItem.sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx;
4. SetDisplayConfig()

This just works for Win7.

---

On Windows 10 RS1 onwards the SetDisplayConfig() will fail with **invalid parameter**. I'm not quite sure why, but i recognized that under Windows 10 the 'ModeInfo.adapterId' (low and high part) changes on each reboot. Additonaly the adapter changes when you duplicate/extend via "Windows-Settings -> Display".
That's why I believe under Windows 10 you have to adjust the adapterid for PathModeInfoArray and SourceModeInfoArray as well.

Problem for now: I don't know how to get the right Adapter id for that purpose. I would be very appreciate if anyone has an answer/tip for solving this problem under windows 10. (I need a working solution for windows 10 :-( )

Comment: Hi. Do you have a working code to share for Windows 10? I've been looking for similar solution where I could mirror or disconnect my AVR.

Comment: @Trm Sorry, I'm afraid I didn't found a working solution for W10 so far. If you'll find a way pls. let me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the primary display first and then SetDisplayConfig()?

ChangeDisplaySettingsEx with CDS_SET_PRIMARY
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx

And then you call SetDisplayConfig to clone.

Comment: I want to clone the desktop between two **secondary monitors**. The primary desktop shall not be affected and show its own content. --> two independend areas (main monitor and clone area [Display 2 and 3])

Comment: Ok, I understand, that may not be possible without extra software.

Comment: There is no API which does the same as a User can do through the control panel? (Selecting two Displays and duplicate between them)

Answer (score 1):

Whole story about duplicating multiple monitors on win 10 is related to setting up target monitor's x and y position to the one found in the source monitor. 
So, first:

- go through the list of all paths, and find indices for source and target monitor (it is good to take only those that are active)
- get x and y position from the source monitor (from mode array - i.e., DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO)
- set target monitor x and y position taken from source
- create new display paths array containing only active paths (it is easy upper active array put into new one.
- call SetDisplayConfig with new path array and existing modes (take into account size of mode and path array