# How to use the SetDisplayConfig functionality in Windows versions lower than 7?

Tags: c++, winapi

The `SetDisplayConfig` available only in Windows 7 and later versions of the Windows operating systems.
But I need functionality like asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790287/programmatically-changing-the-presentation-display-mode/16791451) question in Windows versions lower than 7.

How do that?

How do:

- Computer Only
- Duplicate
- Extend
- Projector Only

without using `SetDisplayConfig`?

Comment: You could attempt to launch (much like `DisplaySwitch.exe` for Windows 7+) the [MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) tool. Make sure you check license and system requirements (later says: "works on any version of Windows, starting from Windows XP") - note, I never tested it. Hence a comment not an answer. Additionaly [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178027/How-to-create-a-display-switcher-for-Windows-XP) might be useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625983/how-to-make-clone-or-extended-mode